# Writing code to a file, and then executing it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python script that imports an existing file in the same directory as a module. How does writing to the file, then using the import to execute it differ from `exec()`? Is it safer?
Here's an example to illustrate what I'm talking about:

```
import example
examplefile = open("example.py", "w")
exampletext = "def examplefunction():\n\tprint('This is an example!')\n\treturn"
examplefile.write(exampletext)
examplefile.close()
example.examplefunction()
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `import example` line go _after_ creating the file?

Comment: No, because the file `example.py` already exists.

Comment: @PythonFanatic: at which point the new file contents won't be loaded; the module has *already* been loaded into memory and won't be loaded again.

Comment: Is that how it works? When I added something much like this in my own code, the updated contents loaded fine. Huh.

Comment: You can just try it: put print statements into the initial file as well as before and after importing and modifying the file, and also write a print statement into the file. Then see which lines get printed, and in what order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's no safer than using `exec()`. Both importing and `exec()` compile the text to bytecode and then execute the bytecode. The generated bytecode will be exactly the same.

The only difference will be that a `.pyc` bytecode cache file can be created for a file on disk, while `exec()` will re-compile the text each and every time. If you generate the file just once, then import it across Python invocations, then writing the file to disk is going to benefit from that cache.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the concise explanation.